# Toshiba Satellite L755 refuses to boot to USB

Tags: windows-10, boot, partitioning, toshiba-laptop, liveusb

A relative loaned us a Toshiba L755 which was upgraded to Windows 10 home.  I installed Ubuntu on it in a dual-boot configuration for some older relatives to use.  Now that we are done with it, I have been trying to restore it back to its Windows-10-only configuration, but I have run into major problems (which admittedly may have been of my own doing).

First, I successfully removed GRUB and used Windows' recovery environment to overwrite the MBR with Windows' own original bootloader...then, I was able to successfully remove the Ubuntu partitions:  Windows 10 booted normally for two test start-ups after this.

Now, here is where I may have messed up:  I couldn't recall whether I had resized the partitions for Ubuntu, and I remember reading that Windows 10 optimally needs around 240GB in its own (C:) partition (it had 140GB).  So, *using Windows' own disk-management tool*, I took the reclaimed space left from the Ubuntu partitions and resized the Windows 10 (C:) partition to 240GB, and then converted the remaining unallocated space into an extended partition (D:) for just regular storage space.  Everything seemed to go well, the program reported no errors.  However, after that, the laptop has failed to boot:  after the Toshiba splash screen, a black screen appears with an unblinking line cursor at the top, and that's it.

Since then, I have tried and failed multiple ways to recover, many of them centering around trying to boot the laptop from USB.  I have attempted this using several recovery USBs I have made (Windows Recovery, Windows 10 Install, etc.)...however, the laptop absolutely refuses to boot from them.  I have tried a number of solutions suggested in other forums:

1. The BIOS boot-order is already set to USB-first.  Interestingly,
   when a USB drive is inserted in the computer pre-boot, the BIOS
   seems to be able to recognize it whenever I check the boot-order (it
   displays the manufacturer), but the laptop just will not boot from
   it.
2. I ensured that the USB actually is bootable.  I have noticed that some USB
   sticks light up and some of them don't, but I have even tested this
   laptop with a proven Ubuntu bootable install USB, and that doesn't
   work, so it's not the USBs or ISO/Install file(s).
3. Some forums suggested changing the boot mode to CSM instead of
   UEFI, but I'm guessing that my BIOS is somewhat older, as *it does
   not even have this option in its Advanced Settings*, like some other
   computers reportedly do.
4. Similarly, there is no option for "secure boot" (although there are
   boot/BIOS password settings...these have been disabled).
5. Fast-boot
   has been disabled.
6. I've ensured any power-saving related settings are not interfering
   (again, this laptop's BIOS may be older:  although it has one or two
   power-saving options, none of them deal with USB).
7. I tried placing FDD first in the boot order (suggested in one
   forum).
8. I tried changing the virtualization option in the BIOS (another
   suggestion).
9. I even tried invoking the laptop's own recovery drive for a master
   reset:  pressing and holding both power and "0" (zero) until the
   laptop beeps.

***NONE*** of these options have changed a single thing...I still only get that black screen with the line cursor at top; the laptop absolutely refuses to boot from any USB inserted.  I am extremely frustrated and I'm at the end of my wits.  At this point, I'm considering using something called PLOP, which I used in the distant past...but that was for installing Linux/Ubuntu; I'm uncertain of whether that would work for starting up a Windows Recovery Disk or a Windows bootloader.  Does *anyone* have any other suggestions?  Is there something I've missed?  Is my laptop "bricked"?  Thanks in advance for your input!

Comment: Which Windows version had it preinstalled? Being from around 2012 and with Window 8 then it's one of the early UEFI, no longer BIOS, and Windows was installed in UEFI mode. Around that time (and with the Windows 8 release) Microsoft made it mandatory to be that way. However, if it came with Windows 7 then all bets are off, it could be BIOS or UEFI.

Comment: Make sure you're "burning" the Windows 10 ISO using the official Media Creation Tool, something that is automatically triggered when downloading the ISO from a Windows OS. Anything else may result in media that boots only in one mode.